# Javascript create array in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm pretty sure this is a basic question but my PHP background is making me unable to solve this. I was also unable to find a solution that came even close in SO.

I have an array of objects containing a value I want to loop and sum. Everything works well but I would like to directly sum those values to another array in the output.

So this is the working function:

```
    function postsCalc(arrayEntry) {
        var postsOutput = [];
        var postLikes = 0;

        for (var i = 0, len = arrayEntry.length; i < len; i++) {
          postLikes += arrayEntry[i].likes.summary.total_count;
        }   

        postsOutput.likes = postLikes;

        return postsOutput;     
    }
```

Output:

```
likes : 55555;
```

Which works well, but can't I push it directly to the array key and avoid having to do the `postsOutput.likes = postLikes`?

Like this:

```
    function postsCalc(arrayEntry) {
        var postsOutput = [];

        for (var i = 0, len = arrayEntry.length; i < len; i++) {
          postsOutput.likes += arrayEntry[i].likes.summary.total_count;
          // or even a multidimensional:
          postsOutput.totals.likes += arrayEntry[i].likes.summary.total_count;
        }   

        return postsOutput;     
    }
```

and that would output the same as above but avoiding the extra step, is this possible in Javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In php you have associative arrays, but in javascript arrays are non-associative (only contain values, not keys). If you want keys - you are talking about objects (and not Arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function on a list to do this:

```
function postsCalc(arrayEntry) {
    var postLikes = arrayEntry.reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b.likes.summary.total_count}, 0);

    return {likes: postLikes};     
}
```

It works like this: `Array.reduce(callback, initialValue)` where callback = `function(a, b)` where `a` is the accumulator (e.g. tracks the sum, etc) and `b` is a representation of the item you're iterating over on the list. `initialValue` is the starting point for the function (e.g. on the first iteration).

Comment: This worked like a charm, it's a very neat solution. I'm going to read more about .reduce because it seems very interesting, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. The Array prototype methods are all very helpful once you get the hang of them.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic javascript would look like (for your first function):

```
function postsCalc(arrayEntry) {
    var postsOutput = {
        postLikes: 0
    };

    for (var i = 0, len = arrayEntry.length; i < len; i++) {
      postsOutput.postLikes += arrayEntry[i].likes.summary.total_count;
    }   

    return postsOutput;     
}
```

or, now that we can assume .forEach exists:

```
function postsCalc(arrayEntry) {
    var postsOutput = {
        postLikes: 0
    };

    arrayEntry.forEach(function(entry) {
      postsOutput.postLikes += entry.likes.summary.total_count;
    }   

    return postsOutput;     
}
```

Comment: In your example I still have to create an empty object to assign the values later and that's what I was trying to avoid. The accepted solution is simpler but that you very much for your help!